# java spring framework code doesn't run

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-mvc

I have this code

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader;*/
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class DrawingApp {
public static void main(String[] args) {


    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring.xml");

    Triangle triangle = (Triangle) context.getBean("triangle");


 triangle.draw();
   }
 }
```

and I got this error

> Jan 17, 2017 11:14:48 PM
>   org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext
>   prepareRefresh INFO: Refreshing
>   org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@6576fe71:
>   startup date [Tue Jan 17 23:14:48 EST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
>   Jan 17, 2017 11:14:48 PM
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader
>   loadBeanDefinitions INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path
>   resource [spring.xml] Exception in thread "main"
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException:
>   IOException parsing XML document from class path resource
>   [spring.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException: class
>   path resource [spring.xml] cannot be opened because it does not exist
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:341)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:174)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:209)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:180)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:243)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:127)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:131)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:522)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:436)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
>     at
>   org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
>     at fahad.DrawingApp.main(DrawingApp.java:14) Caused by:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [spring.xml] cannot
>   be opened because it does not exist   at
>   org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:158)
>     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:328)
>     ... 13 more

---

by the way, the spring.xml file and .classpath are at the same folder,

so what should I have to do to run this code ?

Thanks

Comment: Your `spring.xml` isn't on the runtime classpath. That said, use Spring Boot and [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io), which will autogenerate a fully booting application for you.

Comment: spring.xml should be inside resources folder if you are using maven

Comment: It clearly says - java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [spring.xml]. Add a screenshot of your project structure.

Comment: what do you mean by project structure @SrikanthA

Comment: I'm not using maven, and the spring file is in the project folder @kuhajeyan

Comment: try moving your spring.xml one level up

Comment: I move it to src folder, but when I try to open the eclipse again, I don't find spring.xml file, it disappears from eclipse, but still in src folder !! @kuhajeyan

Answer (score 3):

It has nothing to do with the .classpath file,  spring is expecting to find the spring.xml file in the classpath, meaning in the directories where your class files are stored.

If you follow the maven conventions for laying out your project then you would put the spring.xml under src/main/resources, you can specify it as a source folder in eclipse. At any rate put the file in a source folder with your code. The ide will copy any files it finds there into your classpath.

Comment: so you mean that Drawingapp.java and Triangle. java and spring.xml should be at the same folder which is src/mypackage/

Comment: @khaled: Put spring xml directly under src, not in mypackage.

Comment: thanks it works, I have another question sir, how can I know that I have JIT or not, because I heard that it comes with JVM, I have java 8 update 91, am I fine ?

Answer (score 0):

To clearer picture, Please refer here - [Class Path - Documentation, Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html)

> The class path is the path that the Java runtime environment searches
>   for classes and other resource files
>
> The default class path is the current directory. Setting the CLASSPATH
>   variable or using the -classpath command-line option overrides that
>   default, so if you want to include the current directory in the search
>   path, you must include "." in the new settings.

Also, Please refer [ClassPathXmlApplicationContext](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/support/ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.html). If you place inside src folder, it would be referred.

Need a tutorial???, try the source code here [ClassPathXmlApplicationContext-Tutorial](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0417__Spring/UseClassPathXmlApplicationContext.htm)- it uses ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.

Comment: thanks it works, I have another question sir, how can I know that I have jit or not, because I heard that it comes with JVM, I have java 8 update 91, am I fine ?